# performance inconsistency in c++ application in debian box

Tags: c++, performance, ssh, debian

I built a multi-threaded c++ application, the core of the application is a time sensitive operation which normally takes around 50 ms, I've been seeing a really strange behavior lately, maybe one of you can help me figuring it out.

I am running the application under root account, and when I run it locally from the debian box , time sensitive main functionality takes around 300-400 ms's. If I use another machine for instance, ssh into the original debian machine and run the application remotely from ssh terminal, same time sensitive operation takes around 50 ms's.

Basically I am running the same application on the same machine. The only difference is first one is being run locally, second one is remotely, but still same process runs on the same machine under same user account, that's why I can't understand how I am seeing this drastic performance difference.

If anybody have any idea on what might be going on, I will be really grateful.

Comment: Are printing lots of output?
Possibly ssh buffers the output in a different way allowing the application to run without blocking?

Comment: I am printing some output, but it's like 50-60 lines, evertime the operation completes, can that make that kind of difference.

Comment: It could be. You could as a test try redirecting the output to a file or /dev/null and seeing if the difference is still there, then at least that rules something out or gives you something to look at?

Comment: you are right, I redirected output to /dev/null and seeing performance boost now. thanks a lot for the clue. I should have thought about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was printing lots of output as comments suggested I redirected it to /dev/null and problem is solved.